# Java IndexException

Tags: java, exception

Hi i am getting string index out of bounds exception when i trying to check the following if condition

```
String details="";
if("C".equalsIgnoreCase(reportType.substring(0,1)))
{
 details="CASH BOOK FROM "+startDate+" TO "+endDate+" **"+shortName;
}
else
{
  details="BANK BOOK FROM "+startDate+" TO "+endDate+" **"+shortName;
}
```

`String index out of range: 1`: this is the error message

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide the value of reportType? Seems like it is empty or something.

Answer (score 3):

The error message clearly states that `reportType` is *shorter* than the length of `1` (i.e. empty). This causes an exception to be thrown. You could try somethign like

```
if (reportType.length() >= 1) {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`reportType.substring(0,1)` raises an exception because, `reportType` may be blank(empty). Check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) : `substring` throws:
IndexOutOfBoundsException if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this --

reportType.substring(0, reportType.length() -1)

By doing this you wont exceed the string lenth and hence prevent throwing exception

Comment: In this case, that would *still* throw an exception. The second argument of substring must be greater than the first.